# JavaScript Exception not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out why my code does not throw and display the error message (page is just blank) after I call it with the following statement:

> document.write(add(10,wrong_input));

**program.js**

```
var add = function (a,b){
    if(typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number'){
        throw{
            name: 'TypeError',
            message: 'add needs numbers'
        } catch(e){
            document.writeln(e.name + ': ' + e.message);
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}
```

**program.html**

```
<html>
    <body>
    <pre><script src="program.js"></script></pre>
    <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you looking for the error message?

Comment: You're mixing throw and try.

Comment: I'm looking for it to be display in the browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `throw` statement doesn't have a `catch` clause, `try` does. You should throw and catch separately. For example:

```
var add = function (a,b){
    if(typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number'){
        throw{
            name: 'TypeError',
            message: 'add needs numbers'
        }
    }
    return a + b;
}

try {
    add('foo', 1);
} catch(ex) {
    alert(ex.message);
}
```

Note that I replaced `document.writeln` with `alert`, because the former will overwrite the whole document if it runs after page load. If you want something better looking, manipulate the DOM directly (by changing some element's innerHTML, appending a node, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Your error handling code is slightly off, you can't throw an error and then try and write it out. You either do:

```
if(typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number'){
    document.write("TypeError" + ": " + "add needs numbers");
}
```

Or simply just `throw` it:

```
if(typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number'){
    throw {
        message: "add needs numbers",
        name: "TypeError"
    }
}
```

Then do your `try catch` in your function call. Personally though, I'd say stick with the first.

Answer (score 1):

AS commented by bfaretto, You are mixing throw and try.

throw throws a exception that you define, but you are using it as a try..catch block. Here is how you could use throw and try..catch together.

```
var add = function (a,b){
    try {
       if(typeof a !== 'number' || typeof b !== 'number'){
            var n = {
                name: 'TypeError',
                message: 'add needs numbers'
            };
            throw n;
        }
        // throws an exception with a numeric value
    } catch (e) {
       console.log(e.name);
    }
}
```